# Multivariable calculus problem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $F(x,y)$ is a continuously differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $F(x,y)=0$ is a figure "8" in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane. Then at least, how many solutions does the following system have in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $$F_x(x,y)=0, F_y(x,y)=0$$

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing an hypothesis?

Comment: Let, for simple, your "8"-shaped figure be centered in $(0,0)$.

$(0,0)$ always solves $\nabla F=0$, but I think the exact  cardinality depends on the choice of $F$.

Let, as an example, $F$ have a finite number of solution for $\nabla F=0$ (iI'm pretty sure one can show it exists).

Then, $F^2$ annihilates on the same "8"-shaped set, but $\nabla(F^2)=2F\nabla F$ annihilates also on $\{F=0\}$, whose cardinality is $2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Sorry, I meant to say at least how many solutions